# FFT of np.cos has two peaks

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, fft

For some reason, the following snippet produces an FFT graph with two negative peaks, despite the fact that `wave` only consists of one `cos` and nothing else.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

scale1 = 1.0
scale2 = 1.0e-1
N = 10000
mind = 50
maxd = 250
constantDistance = 200.0
wavelength = 400*scale2
k = 2*np.pi/wavelength
x = np.linspace(mind, maxd, N)
xCalc = (x+constantDistance)*scale1

wave = np.cos(k*xCalc)
fftwave = np.fft.fft(wave)
xfft = np.fft.fftshift(xCalc)

plt.clf()
plt.plot(xfft,fftwave,linewidth=0.25)
plt.show()
```

I've tried `rfft` and it produces one peak (because of the asymmetry), but I need all later outputs (square/triangle window, their FFT and their convolution) to be symmetrical about the "center". Also, is it possible to connect the gap that forms when using `np.fft.fftshift`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of small mistakes in your script and your expectation:

1. A cosine has two peaks in the FT at +freq and -freq because `cos fx = 1/2(exp ifx + exp -ifx)`
2. Where you are using `fftshift` you should be using `fftfreq` instead, since you are plotting in the freq domain

.

```
xfft = np.fft.fftfreq(N, maxd-mind)
```

3. Even though your signal is real its FT is still complex, so you should plot its absolute value and/or angle
4. To get rid of the little gap you can use `np.roll`

.

```
xfft = np.roll(xfft, N//2)
fftwave = np.roll(fftwave, N//2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to remove the gap, so plotting `fftwave = np.absolute(np.fft.fft(wave))` looks pretty good. But does point 1 mean I won't be able to get a single sin peak?

Comment: @bqback If it bothers you just leave out the negative frequencies, you are not losing any information doing that.